# how can i make a twig node path variable multilingual compatible in a view template?

Tags: views, 8, i18n-l10n

I have not found the path field in a view so i have added in my template for views_view_fields.

```
 <div class="cell small-12 event__link">
     {{ fields.view_node.content }}
 </div>
```

This provide the path to the content of the default language.

How can i make a twig variable node path multilingual compatible in a view template?

Comment: Have you checked the `Rendering Language` (middle column in the views UI)? Is a content translation available for the item you want to show?

Comment: not changing anything when displaying   {{ fields.view_node.content }}.

Comment: is there another variable available for the path?

Comment: I don't know of one, but it also shouldn't be necessary. Whenever you render an entity, it should automatically use the correct language. Are you asking for the lang path of a row/item inside the view, or the path to the page display of that view?

Comment: i need each row path to make a link button to the content

Comment: Doing this with Twig logic is wrong. Configure your view correctly. See `Rendering Language` in views admin UI. If using view with fields: add "Link to Content" field. If using view with rendered entity: use normal "{{ url }}" in node template.

Comment: what's the variable name corresponding to 'link to content'?

Comment: Views does not work this way, such a variable does not exist. Try [searching for work-arounds](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bviews%5D+get+field+value+in+twig)

Answer (score 0):

how simple is that ?

```
  <div class="cell small-12 event__link">
      <a href="{{ path('entity.node.canonical', {'node': fields.nid.content|striptags|trim}) }}">
        {% trans %}Read more{% endtrans %}
      </a>
   </div>
```